# Python Selenium Webdriver: How to handle Alert Windows

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

I've webpage wherein I select 'Disable' radio button and click 'Apply/Save' button to apply settings. But unfortunately an Alert window pops saying 'If disabled, the information captured by the Broadband Router will be lost. If you wish to save the current log information, click the "Cancel" button, view the current system log, and use the Save option from the File menu to save the log data.'

How do I click 'ok' button to accept the applied settings?
Please below the screenshot for reference.

Please find below my python code:
Note: My alert.accept() function is not clicking the 'ok' button to apply settings

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/blockquote/form/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[2]/input').click()

try:

   driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/blockquote/form/p/input').click()

   alert = driver.switch_to.alert()

   alert.accept()

except:

   print 'Not disabled'
```

[image]

Comment: do you mean your control is going to the `except` block?

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to automation. If the focus is on OK button, you could try 
    SendKeys.SendWait(@"{ENTER}");
This worked for me in c#.

Answer (score 0):

Try alert command with some wait or sleep to appear. If it is not working you may try with simulating keys. JavascriptExecutor work very well here.

In Java

```
  JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
  js.executeScript("call function to accept");
```

Thanks

Comment: The sleep command before the accept isn't working. Any other way to handle?

Comment: then try with JavascriptExecutor

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old post, but for future reference, I will try to answer the question.

```
alert = driver.switch_to.alert()
```

The above code is incorrect. alert is not a function call, but a variable.

```
alert = driver.switch_to.alert
```

Notice how the next code is missing parentheses. This is the correct code.